# Is it possible to open a deep link in a desktop application?

Tags: url, outlook, linker, deep-linking

I'm developing a link with url that opens an invitation in Outlook for teams to schedule a meeting in MS teams. Turns out that url is a deeplink and I can't access the invite on desktop. I need this link to open in the mobile version and also desktop!
Does anyone know how this type of link works on the desktop?

Thanks!

I am trying with this href="https://outlook.office.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose?body=Learn... but no sucess.